# Finding position of document in a sorted Mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to build a leaderboard type of app using `MongoDB` and `pymongo`, and have a collection that is setup pretty simply where I order it by an integer value.  This makes figuring out the top and bottom users pretty trivial using `sort` and `limit`.

My issue is if I want to search for a user that is in the middle of the collection.  How would I create a query that would be able to determine what position in the ordered collection that user is?

Using this dataset for example:

```
{user: 'A', value: 20}
{user: 'B', value: 10}
{user: 'C', value: 5}
{user: 'D', value: 4}
{user: 'E', value: 1}
```

How would I construct a query that given we are looking for `{user: 'C'}` it returns not only the users document, but also that the user is 3rd in the ordered list?

The next question is once I have this, how do I also determine that user `B` and `D` are in the places around that user?

I already know how to just pull the whole list into my application and do a quick search through it, but that seems like the wrong/expensive answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way that comes to mind for this is to run 2 queries. The first query would be to get the value for the current user. Then using that value subtract/add some constant value from that query to derive a range of users with near values using `$gt` and $lt``.

The tricky thing there is that there might not be any values within the range, so you may need to account for that and possibly run additional queries if that happens.

But this doesn't actually give you the rank which is what you're asking for. If the values (I assume these are some kind of scores) were relatively finite, you could store one or more documents with the individual score values which you could use to know what the adjacent ranges were. Here is a [blog post](http://arturogutierrez.com/creating-an-efficient-leaderboard) proposing a similar idea.

Having to read through a large collection to get the position is going to be inefficient, possibly not acceptable for large `n`. But depending on the scope/scale of your problem that may be the acceptable and the easiest option.

Comment: Multiple documents would be possible... with some kind of cleanup job that runs periodically, I'll keep that in mind if the naive approach proves to be too expensive.